# First value without LIMIT

Tags: mysql, limit

I like to get the first and last name of the last member(s) who signed up without using LIMIT clause in MYSQL. The following code works but my assignment asks me to write the code without LIMIT.

```
SELECT firstname, surname
FROM Members
ORDER BY joindate DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Why? `LIMIT` should work, and if it works, what's the problem? Why do you need a different way?

Comment: In my project, the question is asking it without LIMIT. I don't know why :-)

Comment: @Halis Please [edit] your question to include the assignment/homework to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `WHERE` clause to return only the row(s) with the latest `joindate`:

```
SELECT firstname, surname
FROM Members
WHERE joindate = (SELECT MAX(joindate) FROM Members)
```

Comment: `joindate` is not unique, so you query can return multiple rows

Comment: Why not? The requirement is: *I like to get the first and last name of the last member(s) who signed up*

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL version 8 and above you could alternatively use the `row_number()` window function.

```
SELECT x.firstname,
       x.surname
       FROM (SELECT m.firstname,
                    m.surname,
                    row_number() OVER (ORDER BY m.joindate DESC) rn
                    FROM members) x
       WHERE x.rn = 1;
```

But I doubt this is any better.

Comment: Thank you. It did not work. I think I am missing something. I checked the row_number on the internet. It looked correct but I could not figure out what is wrong.